# Parse json array using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json arry

```
    var students = {"apResults":[{"offid":"267","item_name":"","offer_name":"fsdfsf","stlongitude":"77.5945627","stlatitude":"12.9715987"},

{"offid":"265","item_name":"","offer_name":"vess offer shops","stlongitude":"","stlatitude":""},

{"offid":"264","item_name":"","offer_name":"vess ofer  shop","stlongitude":"","stlatitude":""},
{"offid":"263","item_name":"","offer_name":"ofer frm vess","stlongitude":"77.5943760","stlatitude":"12.9716060"},
{"offid":"262","item_name":"","offer_name":"offer hungamma","stlongitude":"77.5943760","stlatitude":"12.9716060"},
{"offid":"261","item_name":"","offer_name":"offer hungamma","stlongitude":"77.5943760","stlatitude":"12.9716060"},
{"offid":"260","item_name":"","offer_name":"offer1","stlongitude":"77.5943760","stlatitude":"12.9716060"},
{"offid":"259","item_name":"","offer_name":"offer","stlongitude":"77.5943760","stlatitude":"12.9716060"}]}
```

How i can parse this json arry using `json.parse`. I have tried this code

```
    for(i=0;i<students.apResults.length;i++)
{
    var contact = JSON.parse(students.apResults);
    var offid = contact.offid;
    alert(offid)    
}
```

But its giving an error  `JSON.parse: unexpected character`.Edited my question

Comment: What's the error? Which browser?

Comment: What is the use of parsing it. it is already a javascript object
use `students.Maths[i].Name` to access name of each student

Comment: @danwellman - I think you're after quick upvotes here for requesting more information when in fact more information was not required had you have just read the post. Despite the fact it's considered good practice to also provide more details of the error (and often crucial) I don't think it was here.

Comment: @Skonjeet I was asking for more info simple because saying 'I have an error' and then not stating what the error is is like walking into a shop and saying 'I want something' and then stading still and waiting. I am not looking for quick upvotes. Do you even get rep from comment upvotes?

Comment: Before JSON.parse() you have to use JSON.stringify(). You can't send js object to JSON.parse() and that what you are doing now. Look at my answer.

Comment: @danwellman - you do yes - and I'm sure you're fully aware that you also lose reputation everytime you down-vote someone, god knows why you went through my questions and down voted me. You must be bored.

Comment: @danwellman Also - your analogy is completely irrelevant - you could clearly see THOmas had misunderstood the concept of JSON merely from the code that he had posted surely? You could see what THOmas wanted from the shop just from him walking into it if you'd prefer to use your analogy.

Comment: You can't make an attempt at an analogy and then say "it's not meant to be concrete" to back out of it when it's wrong!? My point is - you are wrong when you say "the question is lacking key elements such as error messages." At least 4 people answered the question correctly and gave THOmas the solution prior to seeing these elements that were so 'key' to the question. It's pathetic of you to down-vote my questions, childish. Here you go I'll up-vote your last comment for you, stop you from moaning.

Comment: @SkonJeet You sir have a terrible attitude. Wildly accusing people of asking questions just for rep. As if the entire ecosystem of SO *wasn't* built around rep in the first place. The other answerers answered *after* I left the comment. I downvoted like 2 or 3 of your questions for valid, accepted reasons (the reasons suggested when you downvote). I see you have now downvoted every single question I ever asked so how even more pathetic and childish of you. You have asked *way* more questions than I so I could be a total idiot and do the same to you. And I didn't and would not apologise.

Comment: @SkonJeet. I deleted the comment that you upvoted, not because I don't stand by what I said but because I do not need or want any form of rep from you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(i=0;i<students.apResults.length;i++)
{

    var contact = JSON.parse(students.apResults[i].offid);

    alert(contact)  
}
```

Answer (score 7):

That's not a json string, that's a regular javascript variable:

```
for(i=0;i<students.Maths.length;i++)
{
    var contact = students.Maths[i];
    var fullname = contact.Name;
    alert(fullname) 
}
```

Comment: if i remove Maths and Science is it a json string?

Comment: It's still an object. Here the JSON string representation: `alert(JSON.stringify(students))`

Comment: @THOmas - you need to read more on JSON mate. Think of typical JSON as a big string that can then be interpreted (parsed) by javascript into an actual javascript object. What you have is already the object, you'd be taking a huge step back if you were to want to deal with JSON from an object you already have in order to parse it back as an object.

Answer (score 3):

JSON parses strings, not objects/arrays.

why need parsing when you can access it like `students.Maths[i].Name`

Answer (score 2):

`students` is not a JSON array, it's an actual array. You don't have to parse because it's not a string. So you can access directly to the data you need:

```
for(i=0;i<students.Maths.length;i++) {
    var contact = students.Maths[i];
    var fullname = contact.Name;
    alert(fullname) 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't parse `students` because is not a JSON. It's simple object.

However this will work:

```
var students = JSON.stringify(students); // if you want to send data

students = JSON.parse(students); // after receiving make a object from it

//use like any object    
for(i=0;i<students.Maths.length;i++)
{
    var contact = students.Maths[i];
    var fullname = contact.Name;
    alert(fullname) 
}
```

Of course it doesn't make sense to write it that way unless you send `students` data to other site or program.

**Edit:**
You don't need JSON in this code at all. But if you want to test JSON.parse() do it this way:

```
var students = { ... } // your data

var students = JSON.stringify(students); // students is `object`, make it `string`

students = JSON.parse(students); // now you can parse it, `students` is object again 

for(i=0;i<students.apResults.length;i++) {
    var contact = students.apResults; // no JSON
    var offid = contact.offid;
    alert(offid)    
}
```

That should work.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a javascript object. So, you won't need the JSON.parse

```
for(i=0;i<students.Maths.length;i++)
{
    var contact = students.Maths[i]);
    var fullname = contact.Name;
    alert(fullname) 
}
```

this should be ok

Answer (score 0):

The idea of JSON is for the exchange of objects represented as a structured string (in a nutshell). What you've got there is simply an object. It's unnecessary (and impossible) to parse and object that isn't JSON into a javascript object; what you have is the outcome of what you would expect from a parsed JSON string.